# Recovering reformatted partition

Tags: partition, guid

I have an external drive that had a single HFS+ partition (GPT). It was accidentally formatted. How can I recover the lost partition?
I "know" the old partition map which (coincidentally?) is the same as the new one; starting sectors etc.
Thanks in advance